# Why does the git branch name changes when there are conflicts?

Tags: git, version-control, github, git-bash

I am a newbie using Tortoise Git ONLY to commit/revert and GitBASH to pull and push. (I face some ssh issues to commit using GitBASH and my question is not about it). I've two parts to my question.

I follow the standard way of commit->pull->push. And I usually face mergeissues/untrackedfiles on files which I am not at all working on. Is there something wrong in what I do because of which I face these issues?

The branch name I am working with is Certification and I have observed a thing.
There were some merge conflicts and so in GitBASH the branch name got changed to <`Certification|MERGING`>.

And after resolving the merge conflicts, it changed back to <`Certification`>
Is this behavior expected? Why does it happen?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't actually change the branch name. Because a merge conflict is a significant state, GitBASH is making it obvious to you there is still a conflict to be resolved.

It is possible, with some advanced Bash knowledge, to change the message it gives. I think that is far more advanced to be answered here, but see http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/01/23/bash-git-status.html for some examples.